# Generating functional for scalar expectation values in String Theory (Polchinski 6.2, Volume 1)

Tags: string-theory, path-integral, partition-function

Polchinski defines generating functional as:

> $$\begin{align*}
> Z[J] = \left\langle\exp{\left[i \int d^2\, \sigma J(\sigma) \cdot X(\sigma)\right]}\right\rangle
> \end{align*}\tag{6.2.1}$$

for the calculation of products of vertex operators.
Why is there no $\sqrt{g}$ in the measure? Shouldn't we have the source term follow the worldsheet symmetries?

Comment: J is meant to transform as a density, you can take out to be proportional to $\sqrt{g}$ if you so please. in practical calculations you’ll see that it’s usually more convenient to keep the $\sqrt{g}$ implicit.